# joining list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an object which contains a collection of another object. The collection object has 2 properties, both of which are strings.

For example:

```
public class Department
{
    List<Person> People{get;set};
}

public class Person
{
   string FirstName {get;set;};
   string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Basically I just want to render the names in a comma separated list so they will appear like this:

```
John Smith,
Fred Smith
etc...
```

Is there a way to do this using Linq? I have tried using the Aggregate method, something like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Department.People.Select (x=>x.FirstName).Aggregate((x,y) => x + ",<br>" + y) : "" %>'></asp:Label>
```

This works with 1 string i.e. first name, but cant get it to work when wanting to include the 2nd string i.e. LastName

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Habib: Your edit seems to be incorrect since it suggests that OP actually want to separate each name by a new-line.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, When I tried editing it, the names were on separate lines *in edit mode* , but since they were not in a code block, they appeared in single line, that is why I edited.

Comment: @Habib: His code suggests that your edit was correct since he's using `<br>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I am not sure if you can see that http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20569214/edit/b12c30dd-b387-4340-9058-af6f74a9971e, but that is how it was originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select` and `String.Join`:

```
var people = department.People.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}",
                                  p.FirstName, p.LastName));
string result = string.Join(",<br>", people);
```

Note that i would not use `<br>`'s in ASP.NET but an appropriate control like `ListBox` or a `Repeater`. But that's another issue.

Comment: What if I tell you my first name is `<script type="text/javascript">alert("boo!");</script>` (or something more nefarious)? A good solution to this should include some sort of safe escaping.

Comment: I assume this is another question. I have added that using `<br>`s isn't the best way to display multiple items in ASP.NET. Apart from that, a `Label` will prevent you from simple attacks like this since the text will be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Join` in Code behind like:

```
Label1.Text = string.Join(",<BR />", 
                     Department.People.Select(r=> r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName));
```

Or in ASPX

```
Text='<%# string.Join(",<BR />", 
                         Department.People.Select(r=> r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName)) %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a concat in the select

```
x=>x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

Department data = ...something...;
var names = string.Join(
    ", ",
    data.People.Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName))
);
```